# Can I choose that crossroad option?

Tags: dead-of-winter

Thumbs up option of the crossroad card ("Old divisions") says: Remove 1 helpless survivor

There are no helpless survivors at the colony right now.

Can we choose the thumbs up option in this case or do we have to choose the thumbs down option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules state (p. 12):

> If a player is unable to meet the conditions of an option on a crossroads card, she must choose the other option.

So no, you have to pick the other option.